# Plot 3d points and surfaces in QT 5.7

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, plot, c++14

Anyone knows how to plot 3D surfaces and points in Qt. I looked at qwtplot3d but its rather old, last update 2007. As I understood QT Data Visualization is not open source too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that [Qt Data Visualization is not available under the open source license](https://forum.qt.io/topic/60912/what-is-qt-data-visualization-license), you would have to buy [commercial license](https://www.qt.io/dc-commercial/) in order to use that module.

If you are looking for an open source alternative, Kitware's [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) could be an option. You can [search the internet](https://www.google.com/#q=qt+and+vtk) for many tutorials on how to combine Qt + VTK in your project.

Comment: I think QVTKWidget is only supported for qt 4.8 and lower

Comment: It is indeed. If using VTK, you'd have to implement your own Qt-based widget that supports VTK content output.